# How do I use Apple Keychain?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security, keychain

I am using trying to use [scifihifi-iphone (from Github)](http://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security) to store and retrieve usernames and passwords. However, when I add the class `SFHFKeychainUtils` I get the following errors:

```
  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:
      _kSecAttrAccount$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecReturnAttributes", referenced from:
      _kSecReturnAttributes$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecClass", referenced from:
      _kSecClass$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:
      _kSecClassGenericPassword$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecAttrLabel", referenced from:
      _kSecAttrLabel$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_SecItemUpdate", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:
      _kSecAttrService$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecReturnData", referenced from:
      _kSecReturnData$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:
      _kSecValueData$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I leaving out? When I click the errors, it doesn't take me to any place in the code.

Comment: It looks like a linker error. Is this the first time your code has done anything with Keychain?

Comment: Did you add the Keychain framework too?

Comment: How do I add the Keychain framework to my app?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Add `Security.framework`, then rebuild. Sometimes I find I have to build clean and then rebuild.

To add this, right click on your target in Xcode, then Add->Existing Frameworks and choose (or navigate) to `Security.framework`.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I was looking for a framework called Keychain.framework which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: That solved my problem BUT I had to drag Security.framework into the project from Finder, adding it in the XCode 4.2 "link with libraries" section did not work (it didn't seem to find the framework it had added).